Export Call Log from Android Phone with Android Version 11 and above
How can i export call log from an android phone with android version 11 and above?
Where is the call log file stored and how can I access it?
My end goal is to be able to print the call log, please answer and advise accordingly.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls
